# How to ignore whitespaces on string comparison?

Tags: c#, .net

I have list of strings. At some point I need to check if list contains some string.

For example:

```
  public List<string> Headers { get; private set; }

  Headers = new List<string>();
  Headers.Add("bla1 bla1 ");// pay attention to the whitespace at the end
  Headers.Add("bla2 bla2");
  Headers.Add("bla3 bla3");
  Headers.Add("bla4 bla4");
```

At some point I need to check if list of string contains for example `"bla1 bla1"` string.

For this purpose I use this line of code:

```
var isExists = Headers
    .Where(h =>!h.Equals("bla1 bla1", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

But the result of `isExists` variable is false because headers contains `"bla1 bla1"` string with a space at the end.

How can I ignore `whitespaces` at the start and at the end of the string?

Comment: You shouldn't be parsing a http response using regex which gives you the white spaces.  Use a proper method for getting the data.

Comment: It's probably better to normalize your strings _before_ adding them to collection (by calling `Trim()` on value before adding it to `Headers`).

Answer (score 11):

You can call the [`Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove any white spaces at start and end of string and then followed by `Equals` call on it:

```
h.Trim().Equals("bla1 bla1", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

and in case we want to remove all the white-spaces, we can use `Replace()` like:

```
string name = " Ehsan Sajjad Developer ";
string result = name.Replace(" ",String.Empty); // result EhsanSajjadDeveloper
```

Comment: He could also use `.Replace(" ","")` to remove the whitespace between the words

Comment: that will remove the in between white spaces too, and the OP is looking for removing those from end it looks like

Comment: yeah i just said that. Just gave another option if the user wants to be relieved from all the whitespaces.

Comment: added that too :)

Comment: I like the answer even though it's an answer to a *different* question. OP asked: "How can I **ignore** whitespaces at the start and at the end of the string". This answer provides a way of *removing* spaces not ignoring them... Obviously OP is confused and didn't make himself clear so the answer is correct

Comment: @Fabjan, it is actually kind of ignoring, as the original string will remain with white-spaces, but this is the only way i can think of right now to avoid white-spaces :)

Answer (score 1):

***You could use this regex to remove whitespace from end and beginning of line***

```
string withoutSpace = Regex.Replace("   bla1 bla1     ", @"^\s+|\s+$", "");
Console.Write(withoutSpace);
```

*The Output will be "bla1 bla1"*

Answer (score 0):

A good way of flexibly comparing strings is regular expressions. The "\s*" means zero or more sequence of whitespace. The ^ represents the start of the string and the $ represents the end of the string: meaning that it will not match a string which has anything else in it.

```
// Needs using System.Text.RegularExpressions
var blablaPattern=new Regex(@"^\s*bla1 bla1\s*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var isExists = Headers.Where(h =>!blablaPattern.IsMatch(h))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String1.replace(" ", string.empty).equals(string2.replace(" ", string.empty), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Please add some explaination too instead of just pasting code...